# How to get value from multidimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [like_info] => Array ( [like_count] => 30 ) [comment_info] => Array ( [comment_count] => 6 ) [share_count] => 17 [attachment] => Array ( [description] => Mitkkk kkssk [media] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [src] => com.jpg&cfs=1 ) ) [name] => euch ) [permalink] => example.com/47457343655 [created_time] => 1925 ) ) ) )

how to get value from all the column  in variable listed here

- like_count
- share_count
- comment_count
- description
- src
- permalink
- created_time

Comment: Please add a [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to indicate the language or tool you're trying to do this with. Also post a [mcve] of your attempt at solving the problem and the issues you encountered.

Comment: i got one open source code that solved my problem exactly.Thanks to all for answers

Answer (score 0):

You can make a vector of variables, i mean a single array:

```
$var = array();
```

Then you can do a double loop to get all the values of the multi dimensional array and store them on the vector, like:

```
for($i = 0; i< count($yourarray); i++){
   if(is_array($yourarray[i])){
      for($j = 0; j< count($yourarray[i]); j++) $var[] = $yourarray[i][j];

   }else $var[] = $yourarray[i];
}
```

Comment: i got one open source code that solved my problem exactly.Thanks to all for answers